# ACF into shortcode

Tags: wordpress, laravel-blade

Hello good people of StackOverflow, I was wondering is there any way I can use advanced custom fields in shortcode?

```
  function highlight($atts) {
  return ' 
<div class="col-lg-6 ">
 <div class="highlighted">
  <p class="page-title">TEST</p>
 </div>
</div>';
}
add_shortcode('scbox', 'highlight');
```

so I would like to put something like `{{ the_field('text') }}` where the "TEST" is now, I'm using blade template if its of any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function to obtain the value that you are looking for. (`get_field()` will *return* the value, whereas [`the_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) will print the value wherever invoked.)

You can then concatenate the value into your returned string:

```
function highlight($atts) {
    $text = get_field('text');

    return ' 
    <div class="col-lg-6 ">
      <div class="highlighted">
        <p class="page-title">' . $text . '</p>
      </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: That worked just perfectly, i didn't know you can do that, thank you for fast and good answer George!